# I could not access my website wp-admin after installing SSL. And error with mixed content

Tags: errors, ssl, https

I've this code in `.htaccess` file, and facing lots of mixed content error after installing ssl certificate.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^\/(fractuosity)([0-9]+)\/(.*)([0-9]+)\/(.*)$ ?fractuosity$2=$4&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} celestialspaceindia\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://celestialspaceindia.com/$1 [R,L]

</IfModule>
```

[image]

Comment: You need to use a database migration / search and replace plugin to replace all instances of your HTTP URL with the HTTPS one. Otherwise your database is still pointing to the old insecure URLs.

Comment: But I cannot access wp-admin to add any plugin

Comment: Change your .htaccess file back, clear your browser cache, add the plugin, replace HTTP with HTTPS everywhere, and then restore .htaccess to enforce HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the HTTPS redirect at the top of the htaccess file, not after the WordPress elements. See this page in the Codex for htaccess suggestions: https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess . You need to redirect to https first before doing the WP rules in htaccess.

You may also need to change any http to https in your database. I use a plugin like "Better Search and Replace" to do that, there are other similar options.

And make sure that you change the URL in the wp-option table to https (in two places).